# Angular Rxjs Observable Chain with ngrx store

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am using Angular 7 with ngrx store. The store contains app state, which I am subscribing to in app components on the OnInit. There are couple of variables in store, which are interchangeable (swapped with a button).

Here is my example code in a component.

```
this.appState.getGasStationSushi().pipe(switchMap((sushi) => {
  this.gsSushi = sushi;
  return this.appState.getStarbucksSushi();
}), switchMap((sushi) => {
  this.sbSushi = sushi;
  return this.service.compare(this.gsSushi, this.sbSushi);
}).subscribe((result)=>{
  console.log(result);
}));
```

With a button click in view, user can change both `sushi` values, which is causing the last subscription call twice, which makes sense (RxJS). I could remove `switchMap` and write something like

```
-- gas station sushi susbcription 
   -- star bucks sushi susbcription 
      -- compare
```

I  am not really huge fan of this, I am sure there must be a `rxjs/operator` of sort. Could someone please make a suggestion?

Also, tried `forkjoin`, but with ngrx store it seems like, one need to call `first` or `last` something like below. Here is a reference for the above statement [forkjoinWithstore](https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/333)

```
const $sushiObs = [
  this.appState.getGasStationSushi().pipe(first()),
  this.appState.getStarbucksSushi().pipe(first())
];
forkjoin($sushiObs).subscribe((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

If I use the above pattern, the subscriptions fire for the first time but not after that at all.

Comment: `getGasStationSushi`. I would never eat Sushi from a gas station.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, here is a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6lkbpo) on stackblitz.

Instead of using a store I just created a mock class `SushiState` that returns observables.

```
class SushiState {
  private _gas = new BehaviorSubject(1);
  private _starbucks = new BehaviorSubject(1);

  public get gas() {
    return this._gas.asObservable();
  }
  public get starbucks() {
    return this._gas.asObservable();
  }

  public increaseSushi(n = 1) {
    this._gas.next(this._gas.value + n);
    this._starbucks.next(this._starbucks.value + n);
  }

  public static compareSushi(g: number, s: number): string {
    return `gas is ${g}, starbucks is ${s}`;
  }
}
```

As for the component, here is the code.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  state: SushiState;

  gasSushi: Observable<number>;
  sbSushi: Observable<number>;

  combined: string;
  combinedTimes = 0;
  zipped: string;
  zippedTimes = 0;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.state = new SushiState;
    this.gasSushi = this.state.gas;
    this.sbSushi = this.state.gas;

    const combined = combineLatest(
      this.gasSushi,
      this.sbSushi,
    ).pipe(
      tap((sushi) => {
        console.log('combined', sushi);
        this.combinedTimes++;
      }),
      map((sushi) => SushiState.compareSushi(sushi[0], sushi[1])),
    );
    combined.subscribe(result => this.combined = result);

    const zipped = zip(
      this.gasSushi,
      this.sbSushi,
    ).pipe(
      tap((sushi) => {
        console.log('zipped', sushi);
        this.zippedTimes++;
      }),
      map((sushi) => SushiState.compareSushi(sushi[0], sushi[1])),
    );
    zipped.subscribe(result => this.zipped = result);
  }

  increaseSushi() {
    this.state.increaseSushi();
  }

}
```

If you run it on stackblitz and check the console, you will see the following behaviour:

[image: console output]

If we use combined latest, we combine the observables separately and only care about the latest state, resulting in 2 calls of `console.log`.

We could instead use `zip`, which waits for both observables to emit, before producing an output. This looks like the perfect fit for our "Increase Both" button, but there's a problem: if the `starbucksSushi` get incremented separately (maybe from a different part of the app), the `zipped` version will wait for the gas station sushi to get updated too.

To suggest a third solution, you could use `combineLatest` to combine the sushi counters, and then use `debounceTime` operator to wait for some number of milliseconds before emitting the output.

```
const debounced = zip(
  this.gasSushi,
  this.sbSushi,
).pipe(
  tap((sushi) => {
    console.log('debounced', sushi);
    this.debouncedTimes++;
  }),
  map((sushi) => SushiState.compareSushi(sushi[0], sushi[1])),
  debounceTime(100),
);
debounced.subscribe(result => this.debounced = result);
```

This will react to changes in all the sources, but not more often than `100ms`.

Finally, the reason why you had to do `first()`:

`forkJoin` joins the observables after they complete (which can happen only once, so it's not a good fit for a continuous stream) and is more suitable for "promise-like" work, e.g. HTTP calls, process completions, etc. Incidentally, if you only take one element from a stream, the resulting stream completes after the single emission.

### P.S.

I recommend utilizing the `async` pipe for working with observables (like i've done with the properties

```
gasSushi: Observable<number>;
sbSushi: Observable<number>;
```

and inside the template then

```
<div>
  <h3>starbucks sushi</h3>
  <p>{{sbSushi | async}}</p>
</div>
```

instead of

```
result => this.zipped = result
```

I have used both in this example so you can compare them. From my experience, working with observables gets much easier, once you stop converting "de-observing" them ahead of time and just allow the `async` pipe to do its work.

On top of that, if you use `subscribe` somewhere in your component, you should `unsubscribe` when the component is destroyed - which is not hard at all, but if we never subscribe explicitly, and allow the `async` pipe to do the subscription, it also handles the destruction for us :)